How to batch process with ffmpeg script, but do each step in a loop instead of two stages
I'm a novice script editor. I convert MOV/AVI video files to MP4 format using a script with ffmpeg and then move the files after processing:
for f in *.mov; do ffmpeg -y -i "$f" "${f%}.mp4"; done

mv -f *.mov /Users/me/Videos/mov
mv -f *.MOV /Users/me/Videos/mov
mv -f *.avi /Users/me/Videos/avi
mv -f *.AVI /Users/me/Videos/avi


Currently the script converts all videos, then moves them all to the other folders. Please how can the script be adjusted so that each video is moved immediately after processing (instead of waiting until all are complete)? This would be a great improvement, as sometimes there are a lot of videos and the script gets interrupted for some reason (not a fault of the script). It will make it easier to monitor progress.

Currently I manually tweak the first line changing *.mov for *.avi  Please is there an easy way to handle either video file format/extension, within the same line?

Is there a better way of handling the mv statements which have multiple lines for lower/uppercase? They also give error if there are no files of that type.


Thank you
The above script is functional but will be better with enhancements or changes.

I don't quite understand your script: You convert inside the loop only mov files to mp4. After the loop, you shift mov, MOV, avi and AVI files to a different directories, but leave the converted mp4 in place. If this is really your goal, your script looks fine to me (just the mv statements could be written simpler. Why do you want to rearrange the logic?

Thanks for your comment. After video conversion, each file type (mp4/avi/mov ) needs to be moved by the script. Currently, I manually tweak the file name as per point 2 setting the video file format. I hope to automate all of this. Cheers

Are you really using sh as your tag says or are you using zsh or bash or some other shell? sh, zsh, and bash (the most likely candidates) are 3 different shells and it's important for us to know which one you're actually using so we know what syntax you need to best help you. So please make sure you use the right tag for the shell you're actually using.

hi @EdMorton, I use bash to execute sh files within zsh shell. Mac OS. Thank you

@Matt that's a bit like saying you use awk to execute perl files within python so I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you say that. Do you mean you run zsh as your login shell but call bash foo.sh to execute any file that has a .sh suffix in the hopes that that file's contents are actually bash instead of sh? Or do you have a bunch of files ending in .sh but that contain bash shebangs and you call those from zsh? Or is sh maybe aliased to bash on your system?

Hi @EdMorton, Thanks for your questions. I'm fumbling around doing what is necessary to make things work without understanding how everything works.
I'm using latest OS on Macbook Air M1.
I come from Windows and I'm familiar with batch .bat scripts.
I was told .sh are the equivalent. I've found them very effective.
I checked the shell version I'm running and it tells me zsh.
If my environment or setup is imperfect, I don't care too much today. It's working. I welcome pointers if I should correct things another day.
Much appreciated.
Thanks for your code. I intend to try it.

You're welcome. I won't keep commenting after this but it's important for you to understand that a huge difference between Windows and Unix is that in Unix file extensions are meaningless to Unix. You cannot tell what a file contains by it's extension, just by it's contents. So regarding ".sh" files being equivalent to ".bat" scripts - not really. A file with a ".sh" suffix could contain absolutely anything and in fact executable commands, including shell scripts, should specifically NOT have any extension.

If you create a shell command to print "hello world" you'd put it in a file named prtHello or any other name, not prtHello.sh, so you can reimplement it in C or Java or anything else in future if you like without changing everywhere it's called from. So if you have a file named foo.sh you cannot tell what it contains until you run file foo.sh and/or open it, e.g. in an editor, so you can see it's contents. So do not assume any file ending in .sh contains a shell script, and you have to read the shebang on the first line of any shell script to know which shell it's for. Good luck!

Aha - very interesting, thank you @EdMorton, this is great to know. Cheers

You're looking for something like this:
find . -type d ! -name . -prune -o \
    \( -iname '*.mov' -o -iname '*.avi' \) -exec sh -c '
for src; do
    echo ffmpeg -y -i "$src" "${src%.*}.mp4" &&
    echo mv "$src" "/Users/me/Videos/$(printf "%s\n" "${src##*.}" | tr A-Z a-z)/"
done' sh {} +

Remove both echos if the output looks good.

Thanks oguz ismail, this script has been very helpful. It's taken me a while to experiment with a few things. Can the initial file types be
( -iname '.mp4' -o '.mov' -o -iname '*.avi' ) I'm unsure how to handle three options.
After processing, I wish to move the new mp4 file to another folder, either /mp4  (after conversion from avi or mov) or another folder if mp4 converted from 4K to 720 resolution. I've tweaked the script so the new filename ends with *-720.mp4
You've been enormously helpful, no worries if you can't respond to this.
Cheers
Matt

@Matt I don't have time, post a separate question so others can help. Good day

All good. Much appreciated for your help. Cheers

Based on your comment, you also want to move the converted files away (BTW, this information should go into your question, not into a comment). In this case, I would already create the converted file at this destination.
outbase=/Users/me/Videos
for f in *.mov
do 
  ffmpeg -y -i "$f" "$outbase/mp4/${f%}.mp4"
done
for e in mov MOV avi AVI
do
  mv -f *.$e $outbase/$e:l
done


It sounds like this might be what you're trying to do (untested):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s nocaseglob

for sfx in mp4 avi; do
    for old in *."$sfx"; do
        new="${old%.*}.mp4"
        ffmpeg -y -i "$old" "$new" &&
        mv -- "$new" "/Users/me/Videos/$sfx/"
    done
done

